# Find whether email and username already exist in Firebase Auth in Flutter App

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am using sign up with email in my Flutter app and using Firebase Authentication for the same. How do I show on the sign up page whether the entered email and username already exist in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firebase will return that info as an error message:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password).then((user) {

    // do whatever you want to do with new user object

  }).catchError((e) {
    print(e.details); // code, message, details
  });
```

if the email exists it'll trigger the `catchError`.  it's worth noting that 'details' is the human readable error getter.  'code' and 'message' are useless to an end user, but those are the only two documented on firebase_auth.

Comment: This works! How would I do the same if displayName already exists?

Comment: you'd have to do a check against your own user db.  displayName is not unique in firebase, just email.