# How to know if user is new in firebase?

Tags: flutter

I use Flutter and Firebase.

I do auth with:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)
```

I receive user in return and I want to know if the user is a new one or it is just a regular login.

Comment: I hope this might help you. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51663684/4608334

Answer (score 0):

You can create collection users or node in real-time database and check if there’s user with that Id.