# How to check if email exists in firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a two-step Login form where the user enters their email first, then is taken to the next page where they enter their password. Prior to taking the user to the password page, I want to check if the email entered by the user is valid and whether it exists in firebase. I have read a few posts about using `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`. However, I'm not quite sure how to implement this.

The idea is if the email does exist the user is taken to the password page, however, if the email does not exist a snackbar pops up with a button taking the user to the register page. How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far...

```html
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


    final nextButton = Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 30.0,
      ),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            List<String> userSignInMethods = await auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)(
               email: _emailController.text,
            );
            if (userSignInMethods != null) {
              final page = LoginPassword();
              Navigator.of(context).push(CustomPageRoute(page));
            }
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
            //TODO: Snackbar 
          }
        },
        tooltip: 'Next',
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.define().primaryColor,
        child: Icon(
          AppIcons.next_button,
          size: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` isn't implemented properly, I'm getting an error.

Comment: Handle the error once you catch the exception, because it'll be thrown in the case if email already exists.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an email already exists in Firebase Auth in Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652134/check-if-an-email-already-exists-in-firebase-auth-in-flutter-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't what you are looking for but what I usually do is store the users in a collection in firestore since that allows me to store multiple values for the user like nickname, picture, points etc. If you want some sample code on how to do this, let me know

**EDIT**

This is some code to help you get started.

First set up the firestore and set up a collection named users. Create a document in it with your mail id and add the fields you want for a user in it. If you do not do this you will get an error that the collection cannot be found or firestore is not set up

While signing up, do something like this given the email is in variable email and password in pass

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(email).set((){
   "email":email,
   "pass":pass,
   "nick":nick,//You can add more fields or remove them
});
```

When you want to check if the email exists, do something like

```
QuerySnapshot query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email',isEqualTo:email).get();
if (query.docs.length==0){
   //Go to the sign up screen
}
else {
   //Go to the login screen
}
```

Now to check the password while signing in, do something like

```
QuerySnapshot query = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('email',isEqualTo:email).get();//You can also pass this query as a parameter when you push the login screen to save some time
if (query.docs[0].get('pass')==pass){
   //Go ahead login
}
else{
   //Display an error message that password is wrong
}
```

If you want to store the data to automatically login when the user opens the app next time, look into the [Shared Preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) library.

If you want to pass the user data around, create a class called User()

```
class User {
  String email;
  String pass;
  String nick;

  User(this.email,this.nick,this.pass);
}
```

Then you can pass it around and easily manage the user data

Comment: It seems like this might be a good solution! Could you please provide the code :)

Comment: Yess. Let me add some code

Comment: Check it out. I have added all the code you shall need to login and sign up your user with firestore

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you very much!!

Comment: It is correct answer for given case, but do NOT ever save user password plane text in database and then just compare strings, it is not how its supose to work!

Answer (score 1):

For the method `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` looking at the documentation, `An empty List is returned if the user could not be found.`
It can't be null since that method returning an empty list, so you can check for the length. `userSignInMethods.length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `catch` and `exception`  like as my code. And let me know.

```
try {
  _firbaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: 'ab@gmail.com', 
    password: '123456'
  );
} catch(signUpError) {
  if(signUpError is PlatformException) {
    if(signUpError.code == 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE') {
      /// ab@gmail.com has alread been registered.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea! However I added print("test") in the if statement where you wrote foo@bar.com. nothing was printing. However the terminal was saying that the email already exists. I'm not sure what's wrong here

Comment: This should be comment rather, which you basically copy/pasted code from another SOF question.