# fetchSignInMethodsForEmail returns empty array for existing user

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using Firebase Email and Password Authentication.

I can see the user in my Firebase console, and the user can log in and log out.

In my code, I'm doing this:

```
const signInMethods = await fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(getAuth(), email);
```

But `signInMethods` is an empty array (as opposed to the expected `['password']`).

Any idea why this should happen?

Expected behavior:
The value returned from `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` should reflect the sign in methods available for the user who just registered with a `password`.

Actual behavior:
The value returned from `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` is an empty array.

Reproduction instructions:

- Clone https://github.com/YonatanKra/tauri-demo/
- Checkout the `add-firebase-auth` branch
- Add a `.env` file with the following details:
  VITE_FIREBASE_APP_KEY=***
  VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=***
  VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=***
  VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID=***
  (replacing the *** with actual details) of a Firebase app with email and password login enabled
- run `npm i`
- run `npm run dev`
- go to the address stated in the console to see the UI
- Enter email and password and login.
- See that the user appears in the Firebase console
- Refresh the app to return to the login screen
- Set a debug point at the `auth.ts` file on line 10.
- login with same credentials
- See that the value returned is an empty array

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No error, just returns an empty array instead of the expected result.

Comment: When you call `getAuth()` you must pass a `FirebaseApp` instance, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#add-initialize-sdk

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks, but that didn't do it :(
It was actually connected to the app because it did register the user.

Comment: I just checked the REST API. It also returns `undefined`, so I believe the issue is deeper than the JS SDK.

Comment: And another check is to see that even without sending `app` to `getAuth` (e.g. using `getAuth()` and not `getAuth(app)` I can still see the app inside `auth` that returns from `getAuth()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting in September 15 email enumeration protection is enabled by default for all new firebase projects. This actually breaks the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` method.

As per the documentation: "A list of sign-in methods for a specified email address is no longer returned when calling the `createAuthUri` REST API or the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` client SDK method on all platforms".

For more details you can check the full [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection).

In order to make it work again you would have to disable the email enumeration protection. To do so you should get an access token for your project by running:

`gcloud auth print-access-token --project=PROJECT_ID`

And then make a patch request as detailed in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#rest):

```
curl -X PATCH -d "{'emailPrivacyConfig':{'enableImprovedEmailPrivacy':false}}" \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-User-Project: PROJECT_ID' \
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/config?updateMask=emailPrivacyConfig"
```

Comment: Or you can do this: from Firebase web console go to Authentication > Settings > User Actions  and un-check 'Email enumeration protection (recommended)'